# Extracting picture from picturebox with handleref

Tags: c#, windows, expression, webcam, encoder

I am using Microsoft Expression Encoder to capture images from the webcam..

Presumably, this code is used to assign the image to the picturebox (**panelVideoPreview**):

```
_deviceSource.PreviewWindow = new PreviewWindow(new HandleRef(panelVideoPreview,panelVideoPreview.Handle));
```

This all works fine, but as soon as I try this:

```
panelVideoPreview.Image.Save("C:\\Temp\\Temp3.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

It says that the Image property is null. How can I get around this?

Any possible suggestions are appreciated!

Regards,
Corné Vermeulen

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is HandleRef isn't finished...
Have you tried to Await the Object?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it, would it be possible to elaborate? Is it Monitor.Wait?